# Whats the best way of getting a list of a field from a object?

Tags: scala, scala-option

So right now I have a list of a object with a Optional Field like this in scala

```
case class Foo(
                   id: String,
                   description: String,
                   OptionalTag: Option[String],
)
```

What I want is to iterate through the list of objects and only get the Optional Tags if they exists, my current approach is this

```
     Tags = listOfFoos.map(foo =>
        if (foo.OptionalTag.isDefined) {
          foo.OptionalTag.get
        } else {
          ""
        }
      ).filter(_ != "" -> "")
```

However Im sure theres a better way to do this then go over the entire list twice but I can not figure it out.

Comment: `val tags = foos.collect{case Foo(_,_,Some(tag)) => tag}`

Comment: `listOfFoos.flatMap(_.OptionalTag)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific problem you mention, `flatMap` is the best solution:

```
listOfFoos.flatMap(_.OptionalTag)
```

If you want to do more complex processing, `collect` is the best choice because it can do the job of both `filter` and `map`:

```
listOfFoos.collect{ case (_, _, Some(tag)) => "Tag is " + tag }
```